# How to configure NGINX to distribute PWA in https

Tags: nginx, progressive-web-apps, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to redirect an APP that already works, to https.

The app is a PWA that is running locally, on 8080 port.

I know that's something in my configuration, because the root works ok, but the sub apps doesn't.

The root is just a html with the routes for the sub apps.

This is the app that I'm trying to redirect: https://github.com/PolymerLabs/multitenant-prpl

This is my configuration file, that I've made with searching around and mixing things into the main nginx configuration file.

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    upstream node-app {
        least_conn;
        server 192.168.0.9:8080 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name _;

        # https redirection
        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }

    server {
        # http2 setup
        listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

        server_name node-app;

        # ssl setup
        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/certs/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/nginx.key;
        ssl_dhparam         /etc/nginx/certs/dhparam.pem;

        # server redirection
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://node-app$request_uri;
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;        
        }
    }
}
```

Probably something is missing.

Thanks in advance.

Images:

The root working.

[image]

[image: 502]

Another route with the dev tools open, the error is a bit longer.

[image: Get 502]

Comment: What you mean by sub app doesn't ? What happens? Can you also list examples of urls? What do you in browser developer tools network tab? Also change your `proxy_pass http://node-app$request_uri;` to just `            proxy_pass http://node-app;`

Comment: @TarunLalwani, thanks for the comment, I've changed the proxy_pass, but not work too.

The server is responding with 502 error

Comment: Can you check the issue for security? I am assuming something from your html is sending back http urls for JS and that is creating problems